# Spring Data save method stopped to work after migration from spring boot 2.7 to 3.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data

I'm trying to migrate Spring Boot from version 2.7.17 to 3.0.5, together with Hibernate (5->6.2.0 Final).
I have a parent-child relationship in my project (look at the code below). To save or update the `Order`, I'm using the `save()` method from `org.springframework.data.repository.Repository` interface (my `OrderRepository` extends it).
After the migration the `save()` method stopped to work. In this statement, I mean that 'parent' reference in `OrderDetails` became `null` after calling `save()` method. Before calling `save()`, the reference is properly set (again, it was working before the migration).
I have no idea in which direction to look and what has changed in version 3. Could you please point me what could be wrong?
Thank you in advance.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "ORDER")
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@NamedEntityGraph(
        name = "Order.orderDetails",
        attributeNodes = {
                @NamedAttributeNode("orderDetails")
        }
)
public class Order {

    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private String orderId;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(
            name = "SITE_SPECIFIC_DETAILS_COMMAND",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "orderId")
    )
    private Set<OrderDetails> orderDetails;

    // rest of the code omitted for brevity
}
```

and

```java
@Embeddable
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder(setterPrefix = "with")
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@Data
public class OrderDetails {

    @ToString.Exclude
    @Parent
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private Order parent;

    @Type(JsonType.class)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    private OrderData data;

    // rest of the code omitted for brevity
```

The repository:

```
public interface OrderRepository extends Repository<Order, String> {

   @EntityGraph(attributePaths = {“orderDetails”})
   Order save(Order order);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure about those version numbers? Spring Boot 3.0.0 comes with Hibernate 6.1.5.Final. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.0.0/reference/html/dependency-versions.html

Comment: Yes, you're right. I was trying to play with the versions, but it doesnt solves the problem.

Comment: An `@EntityGrapgh` on a `save` method doesn't look right to me. Finally make sure you are setting both sides of the relation so adding to the set and setting the `parent` field. Also `Repository` is only a tagging interface, to reuse the `save` method you would need the `CrudRepository` or `JpaRepository`. Next to that it lacks an `@Transactional` and `@Modifying` annotation as well.

Comment: My main question is: why solution mentioned above was working fine before the migration?

Comment: Moreover, CrudRepository still uses em.merge() method under the hood which seems cause the issue. Transaction is started in another part of the code (on the service). Here I've listed only most crucial part.

Comment: Does anyone could help me?